# Loading state in Pages routes, Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lazy-loading

Like we have an easy way to implement a loading component in App routes, what can I use with Pages routes? I tried using suspense, useEffect, and next/dynamic. What is the best way to accomplish this? For example, I'm building an e-commerce website and I am using getServerSideProps to fetch the products. I dynamically imported all components that have products and assigned them a loading state. However, when I first enter the webpage, there is a significant delay before anything is displayed on the screen.

```
const Main = dynamic(() => import("../components/home/main"), {
  loading: () => (
    <div className="mt-[10px]">
      <Skeleton
        highlightColor="#9ca3af"
        baseColor="#E3E0F3"
        className="h-[430px]"
      />
    </div>
  ),
});
```

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  db.connectDb();
  let products = await Product.find()
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate({
      path: "category",
      model: Category,
    })
    .lean();

  return {
    props: {
      products: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products)),
    },
  };
}
```